# Why does mi interpolation search not return the corresponding index when the searched key is the last vector value?

Tags: c++, linear-interpolation

I am trying to create an interpolation search algorithm using both a linear search and a binary search that only splits in half the list once. For both circumstances, the algorithm works except when the desired value is the last item in the vector, in which case the valIndex variable returns an unexpected result. For all other cases, the correct index is returned. What is wrong with my linear and binary loop that does not allow the index of the last item to be returned?

Linear Search

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    int listVal;
    int searchedVal;
    int valIndex;
    vector<int> orderedList;

    cout << "Enter the ordered list: " << endl;

    while (cin >> listVal && cin.peek() != '\n') {
        orderedList.push_back(listVal);
    };

    cout << "Enter the desired key: " << endl;
    cin >> searchedVal;

    //Linear Search
    for (int i = 0; i < orderedList.size(); i++) {

        int currVal = orderedList.at(i);
        
        if (currVal == searchedVal) {
            valIndex = i;
        }

    };

    cout << "The index of the key is: " << valIndex << endl;

};
```

Binary search

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    int listVal;
    int searchedVal;
    int valIndex;
    vector<int> orderedList;

    cout << "Enter the ordered list: " << endl;

    while (cin >> listVal && cin.peek() != '\n') {
        orderedList.push_back(listVal);
    };

    cout << "Enter the desired key: " << endl;
    cin >> searchedVal;

    //Binary Search
    if (searchedVal == orderedList.at(orderedList.size() / 2)) {
        valIndex = orderedList.size() / 2;
    } else if (searchedVal < orderedList.at(orderedList.size() / 2)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < orderedList.size() / 2; i++) {
            if (orderedList.at(i) == searchedVal) {
                valIndex = i;
            };
        };
    } else if (searchedVal > orderedList.at(orderedList.size() / 2)) {
        for (int j = orderedList.size() / 2; j < orderedList.size(); j++) {
            if (orderedList.at(j) == searchedVal) {
                valIndex = j;
            };
        };
    };

    cout << "The index of the key is: " << valIndex << endl;

};
```

Comment: You never put the last element into `orderedList` to begin with. Right after `cin >> listVal` reads the last element, `cin.peek()` returns `'\n'` and `orderedList.push_back(listVal);` is not executed. Then you search for the element that doesn't exist in the vector. Further, your implementation leaves `valIndex` uninitialized, containing random garbage, when the matching value is not found.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Then how should I update my code so that it reads the last value, and stops accepting more input after hitting enter?

Comment: The simple fix would be something like `while (cin >> listVal) {orderedList.push_back(listVal); if (cin.peek() == '\n') break; };` Or, use `std::getline` to read a line of text into a string, then parse numbers out of that string.